# ¿cómo puedo meter dos o más variables a un archivo? sólo se introduce una y termina el programa

Tags: c, variables

estoy tratando de meter 12 variables char en un archivo de texto, esto con el fin de generar al final del programa un archivo de texto que contenga los valores de las variables.
Este es mi primer trabajo en C después de varios hola mundo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char nombre[40];
    char n_ord[6];
    printf( "Introduzca su nombre (40 letras máximo): " );
    scanf( "%s", nombre );
    printf( "Introduzca el numero de orden (6 digitos máximo): " );
    scanf( "%s", n_ord );
    FILE* archivo;
    archivo = fopen("ordennum.txt", "wt");
    fputs((nombre), archivo),("\n");
    fputs((n_ord), archivo),("\n");
    fclose(archivo);
    printf("Proceso completado");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: usando una sola variable, la del nombre por ejemplo, el programa genera el archivo de texto sin problema, pero al agregar la segunda, n_ord, sólo ejecuta una sola variable, la primera.

Comment: ya me di cuenta que no puedo agregar espacios, corta el nombre con el primer espacio, lo agregué con puntos. daniel.zuniga.aguilar, pero aún con eso no escribe la segunda variable. Gracias por responder.

Comment: ok, limpié el cache del devc++ y ya ejecuta las dos variables, algo de mis errores estaba ahí atorado, y efectivamente, copia las dos variables en la misma línea, ¿puedes ayudarme a que cada variable quede en una línea o con un espacio entre ellas?  Saludos y gracias

Comment: Daniel he agregado una respuesta agrupando y extendiendo todo lo que he ido comentando, mira a ver si resuelve tus dudas, en caso contrario comenta.

Answer (score 2):

Dos observaciones:

1. **`scanf("%s", ...)` lee cualquier número de caracteres deteniéndose en el primer carácter en blanco que encuentre. Al terminar agrega un carácter nulo `\0` al final de la secuencia.**

   De esto extraemos un par de problemas:

   - `scanf` dejará de leer cuando encuentre un espacio, dejando el resto de la cadena en el buffer. Si ingresas una cadena con un espacio, tu primer `scanf` lee hasta encontrarlo y almacena eso en `nombre`. Tu segundo `scanf` continua leyendo lo que se dejó el primero en el `buffer` (hasta encontrar un carácter en blanco) y lo almacena en `n_ord`.
   - `scanf` es inseguro por naturaleza. Primero debes tener en cuenta que si tienes un array de 6 caracteres no puedes almacenar una cadena de 6 caracteres, debes reservar uno para el carácter nulo. Es más, si el usuario ingresa más caracteres de los que el array puede contener a `scanf` le da exactamente lo mismo, por lo que termina escribiendo (o intentándolo) en memoria que no le pertenece (overflow).

   Aunque ambos problemas se pueden paliar (por ejemplo, podemos limitar el número de caracteres que debe leer: `scanf("%5s", n_ord);` ), te aconsejo usar [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) si quieres poder ingresar cadenas con espacios y protegerte del desbordamiento de memoria.
2. `fputs((nombre), archivo),("\n");` no hace lo que esperas, que es agregar el carácter de nueva línea al final de la cadena. Date cuenta que `("\n")` está fuera de la llamada a la función, por lo que no tiene efecto alguno en cuanto al archivo. Por otro lado los paréntesis alrededor de `nombre` son totalmente superfluos en este caso.

   Para agregar una nueva línea tienes varias opciones:

   - Llamar a `fputs("\n", archivo)` después de agregar la linea.
   - Llamar a `fputc('\n', archivo)` después de agregar la línea.

El código podría quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char nombre[41];
    char n_ord[7];

    printf( "Introduzca su nombre (40 letras máximo): " );
    fgets(nombre, 41, stdin);
    if ((strlen(nombre) > 0) && (nombre[strlen(nombre) - 1] == '\n'))
        nombre[strlen(nombre) - 1] = '\0';
    // Si el usuario ingresó más de 40 caracteres debemos limpiar el buffer.
    char t;
    while ((t=getchar()) != '\n' && t != EOF){
    }

    printf( "Introduzca el numero de orden (6 digitos máximo): " );
    fgets(n_ord, 7, stdin);
    if ((strlen(n_ord) > 0) && (n_ord[strlen(n_ord) - 1] == '\n'))
        n_ord[strlen(n_ord) - 1] = '\0';

    FILE* archivo;
    archivo = fopen("ordennum.txt", "wt");
    fputs(nombre, archivo);
    fputc('\n', archivo);
    fputs(n_ord, archivo);
    fputc('\n', archivo);
    fclose(archivo);
    printf("Proceso completado");
    return 0;
}
```

`fgets`, si no se ha superado el tamaño asignado, deja de leer ante el primer carácter de nueva línea que encuentre, pero lo consume y **lo incluye en la cadena**. Es decir, ante:

```
char num[6];
fget(num, 6, stdin);
```

si ingresamos:

> 123456789

`num` queda como:

```
12345\0
```

si ingresamos:

> 123

`num` queda como:

```
123\n\0
```

Para eliminarlo hago uso de:

```
if ((strlen(n_ord) > 0) && (n_ord[strlen(n_ord) - 1] == '\n'))
    n_ord[strlen(n_ord) - 1] = '\0';
```

cierto es que se puede recurrir a:

```
strtok(n_ord,"\n");
```

el problema es que falla (mejor dicho, no elimina nada) si la cadena solo contiene `\n`, por ejemplo si el usuario ingresa una cadena vacía.

---

Lo ideal es meter el código encargado de leer cada entrada y de limpiar el buffer en una función para evitar repetir código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya capturé las 12 variables y trabajo para poner lo demás en otro módulo, voy a poner la estructura para escribir en el archivo en una función, la otra parte para crear una posible orden de compra en otra función, la parte de captura de variables va a ser la principal. Muchas gracias. Algún día conoceré tanto como tú.